# How to remove Erlang/OTP 19 and install 18?

Tags: erlang, ubuntu-14.04

I have ubuntu 14.04, I'm working in project with elixir and I need to have the erlang/otp 18, how ever in an actualization of the systems I assume the last version of erlang was install and this it's causing me errors in my projects, so I have been trying to remover erlang/otp 19 and install 18. But I haven't been able to remove it.

when I try with ´sudo apt-get purge erlang*´ I get this error

```
E: No se ha podido localizar el paquete erlang-solutions_1.0_all.deb
E: No se pudo encontrar ningún paquete con la expresión regular «erlang-solutions_1.0_all.deb»
E: No se ha podido localizar el paquete erlang-solutions_1.0_all.deb.1
E: No se pudo encontrar ningún paquete con la expresión regular «erlang-solutions_1.0_all.deb.1»
E: No se ha podido localizar el paquete erlang_solutions.asc
E: No se pudo encontrar ningún paquete con la expresión regular «erlang_solutions.asc»
```

it saids that all those packege haven't been found. And kerl it's not working when I try to get the list of all the versions releases it returns nothing.

how can I uninstal erlang/otp 19 ? or is it another way do to go back to erlang/otp 18 ?

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question, but could help you in the long run. You might consider using kerl to manage your erlang instances. https://github.com/kerl/kerl

Comment: Yes, just use `kerl`. Make sure you grab a recent version from github, and then run `kerl update releases` to make sure your list of available releases is up to date.

Comment: Please read the question, in there I said that kerl it's not working either, I haven't been able to get the list of versions available.

Comment: I read the question, which is why I told you how to update the versions known to your `kerl` installation.

Comment: You probable run that command in a directory containing `.deb` files. `sudo apt-get purge 'erlang*'` might work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally was able to fix the problem, the problem was that I couldn't update the list of releases for kerl, I keep getting 0 releases available.

I fix the problem by doing creating a sh file with the following lines

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Setting up erlang 18.0 with elixir 1.2.4 ..."

sudo apt-get install libssl-dev ncurses-base
curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yrashk/kerl/master/kerl
chmod a+x kerl
sudo mv kerl /usr/bin
kerl build 18.0 18.0
mkdir -p ~/.kerl/versions/18.0/
kerl install 18.0 ~/.kerl/versions/18.0/
echo '' >> ~/.bashrc
echo '. $HOME/.kerl/versions/18.0/activate' >> ~/.bashrc
exec $SHELL

curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/taylor/kiex/master/install | bash -s
echo '' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'test -s "$HOME/.kiex/scripts/kiex" && source "$HOME/.kiex/scripts/kiex"' >> ~/.bashrc
exec $SHELL
kiex install 1.2.4
echo '' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'source $HOME/.kiex/elixirs/elixir-1.2.4.env' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Basically reinstalling and building again kerl, first I ran the sh and got the error I didn't have that version available so I ran kerl update releases and this time it did update the list of releases, then I ran the sh file again.

So I hope this helps someone else.